# sum tow array validation in laravel should be zero

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

hi i have project on `laravel 5.6`
and this is my role for `validation`

```
'voucher_debt' => 'required|array|min:1',
'voucher_debt.*' => 'nullable|numeric|min:0.001',
'voucher_credit' => 'required|array|min:1',
'voucher_credit.*' => 'nullable|numeric|min:0.001',
```

my problem thats i need it to check if the

```
array_sum($voucher_credit) - array_sum($voucher_debt) == 0
```

i tried many thing nothing works out with me 
is that possible on `laravel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this in your request:

```
public function rules()
{
   $rules = [
          'voucher_debt' => ['required', 'array', 'min:1'],
          'voucher_debt.*' => ['nullable', 'numeric', 'min:0.001'],
          'voucher_credit' => ['required', 'array', 'min:1'],
          'voucher_credit.*' => ['nullable', 'numeric' ,'min:0.001'],
   ];

   if (array_sum($this->get('voucher_debt')) - array_sum($this->get('voucher_debt')) == 0) {
       throw new ConflictHttpException('YOUR_MESSAGE');
   }
}
```

Or you can make your custom validation rule and add to `voucher_debt` key

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: i gat this error Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ ConflictHttpException
YOUR_MESSAGE

Comment: yeah, thats right, or you need ValidationException? if your validation failed laravel throw validation exception, but in your case i think need conflict exception